# Doing a SUMIF in SQL

Tags: sql

I'm having trouble explaining it in SQL but I want to do the following excel formula:

```
=SUMIF(C:C,"<"&C4,A:A)
```

in SQL.

```
SUM(CASE WHEN C < A.... doesn't work.
```

[image: Image below of excel]

Any help would be greatly appreciated it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the expression you are looking for is:

```
select sum(a) over (order by b range between unbounded preceding and b - 1)
```

Some databases don't support the full range of window frame options.  You can also express this as:

```
select (sum(a) over (order by b range between unbounded preceding and current row) -
        sum(a) over (partition by b)
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL analogue would be something like

```
SELECT SUM(A) FROM TABLE WHERE C < A
```